# How to (bulk) delete list of a few hundred Files in an Amazon S3 Bucket

Tags: amazon-web-services, image, amazon-s3, image-processing

Being somewhat new to using Amazon S3, we are just beginning to place a large number of our Images in a single bucket.

Could someone possibly help me understand the easiest way for us to Delete a selected list of Images that are sitting in one bucket?

We don't want to delete all of the images that are in the bucket, only a a few hundred of them. Not sure if there is a straightforward way to accomplish this with a simple file import option or not. Or is XML coding required?

Also, is there a way to simply run a report that would produce a report (in CSV form) that shows which files are in a given bucket?

Thanks for any help!

- James

Comment: What OS do you use (locally)?

Comment: What format is this selected list of files in? Is it a `bash` array? Or in a text file, with one file per line? Something else?

Comment: Thanks Mark. Locally am using Windows 8.1  The selected list is in a text file with one file per line.

Comment: You are going to need something like `FOR /f "delims=" %%G in (files2delete.txt) DO @aws s3 rm s3://SomeBucket/%%G`

Answer (score 0):

There are lot of documentation around delete,

https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/reference/s3/rm.html

You can either delete them individually or delete them in bulk or in parallel.

Hope it helps.